# Gravity Forms for WooCommerce – Slow Loading / Add a spinner

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, loading, gravity

I'm building a form using the Gravity Forms WooCommerce add-on that uses a bit of conditional logic.

I'm finding that the initial form load is very slow. 
Also when selecting options from drop-down menus that inform  the conditional logic there's a lag with the form in displaying the new fields.

I've tried to break the form up using the page breaks / multi-page with little improvement.

I'd be prepared to add a loading spinner when a user selects an option - at least to indicate that something is happening. I don't think the Wordpress gforms are ajax by default so I'm not sure how I would achieve this.

Does anyone know how to streamline gravity forms with conditional logic for speed or how to implement a global spinner when the page is processing conditional logic... eg. some sort of  onchange or something like that?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

B